# property 'update' does not exits on type Observable - Ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic3, angularfire2

I am updating ionic2 to 3 / also Angularfire2.

**importing**:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"
```

**constructor**:

```
constructor(private _af: AngularFireDatabase) {}
```

**Have function:**

```
 createProcess(uid: string, process: Process) {
    const newProcessKey = this.getProcesses(uid).push(process).key;
    return this.getProcess(uid, newProcessKey).update({ status: 1, liked: false }).then(() => newProcessKey);
  }
```

**getProcess function:**

```
  getProcess(uid: string, processId: string): Observable<Process> {
    return this._af.object(`/process/${uid}/${processId}`);
  }
```

I am getting error:

*property 'update' does not exits on type Observable*
*property 'push' does not exits on type Observable*

Comment: [Apparently](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#api-summary), object() returns an AngularFireObject. That should be the return type of getProcess(), instead of Observable<Process>.

Comment: @Apparently I am new here. can you give me suggestion how to return correctly?

Comment: Change the return type of `getProcess()` to `AngularFireObject` instead of `Observable<Process>`

Comment: If you don't understand what the return type of a method is, take a step back and learn TypeScript before going further. Replace `getProcess(uid: string, processId: string): Observable<Process>` by `getProcess(uid: string, processId: string): AngularFireObject<Process>`

Comment: now I am getting error: import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject  } from 'angularfire2/database'; about AngularFireObject   - is this right import?